# Why does Chrome let background colors overlap borders?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, background, border

When I run the fiddle in Chrome 49.0.2623.75 on Mac OS X 10.11.3 and adjust the page so that the three colored spans overlap, I'm surprised to see that the green background overlaps the first red span's border. Firefox preserves both with no overlap. This is undesirable behavior from my perspective. Is this a bug? Is anyone else bothered by this? Do you have a workaround? Thanks!

[image]

HTML:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <span class="bg_red border">consectetur adipiscing</span> elit. In ut sapien quam. Cras
    leo dui, ullamcorper sed magna ac, pretium finibus neque. Sed <span class="bg_green">rutrum aliquet aliquam</span>.
    Suspendisse quis dolor pharetra, interdum diam in, condimentum risus.
    <span class="bg_red border">Suspendisse maximus</span>, odio vitae iaculis suscipit, libero diam sagittis magna,
    non luctus eros lorem quis nisl. Donec at tristique felis. Nulla at dui dignissim, rutrum orci vitae, finibus
    neque.</p>
```

CSS:

```
.bg_green {
    background: green;
}

.bg_red {
    background: red;
}

.border {
    border: 4px solid black;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oa59w1tx/

Comment: "This is undesirable behavior from my perspective." What is the desired behavior? From my perspective, both Chrome and FireFox overlap similarly: https://imgur.com/Wommms7&nq3cL1k

Comment: Would reading an elaborate description of [Stacking Conexts](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/zindex.html) bend your desires? Apparently, Chrome is following standards.

Comment: A workaround? Sure, increase the <p>'s line-height. But... I can't see the difference between Mozilla and Chrome either.

Comment: I think this is not problem with chrome it just normal `span`'s `line-height` behavior. If you change it to `display-inline-block` its fixed i think https://jsfiddle.net/oa59w1tx/2/

Comment: @NenadVracar nailed it! Thanks so much :-) Weird that Firefox does this by default?

Comment: It doesn't... `:)`. Also i forgot to say main point here and that is `span` by default is `inline` element and `inline` element calculate `line-height` in different way then `block` or `inline-block` elements

Comment: @MatthewCornell Do you have a _user stylesheet_ in Firefox?

Comment: @MrLister no, never heard of it

Answer (score 0):

```
p span{
     display:inline-block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oa59w1tx/3/